# How to add numbers between strings in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a mixed list with strings and ints and I need to get to the sum of the numbers between each strings. Ideally the end result would be a list of tuples since each string and following numbers belong together (so order is important).

I can extract the number with iteration using `isinstance` but the actual list is very large and I sometimes I have 1 or 2 numbers for each string.

```py
my_list = ['a', 2, 1, 'b', 3, 'h', 50, 4, 'd', 4, 'v', 20, 7]

ideal_output = [('a', 3) ('b', 3), ('h', 54), ('d', 4), (v, 27)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
my_list = ['a', 2, 1, 'b', 3, 'h', 50, 4, 'd', 4, 'v', 20, 7]

from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby(my_list, key=type) # group-by the type of the value

result = []
for key, group in groups:
    string = next(group) # get the string first, we'll skip over it otherwise
    if key is str:
        _, values = next(groups) # move the generator forward to get to the numbers
        result.append((string, sum(values))) # sum up the numbers
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('h', 54), ('d', 4), ('v', 27)]
```

It does assume that there will be at least one number between the strings. If not you can check on the `len` of `g` and if that's more than 1, add a 0 for the value of the first value in `g`

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the `if k is str`. `k` is always going to be a string.

Comment: Good solution, but your single-letter variable names are killing me. And `s = list(g)[0]` can we simplified to `s = next(g)`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Force of habit - need to validate inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple iteration as well without `groupby`, this will be slightly faster because it only does one pass:

```
my_list = ['a', 2, 1, 'b', 3, 'h', 50, 4, 'd', 4, 'v', 20, 7]
new_list = []
new_element = []
for element in my_list:
    if isinstance(element, str):
        if new_element:
            new_list.append(tuple(new_element))
        new_element = [element, 0]
    else:
        new_element[1] += element
if new_element:
    new_list.append(new_element)
print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('h', 54), ('d', 4), ('v', 27)]
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works well for my actual case.

Answer (score 0):

With [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function:

```
from functools import reduce

def accum(prev, curr):    # prev - previous item, curr - current item
    if prev == [] or isinstance(curr, str):
        prev.append((curr, 0))
    elif isinstance(curr, int):
        prev[-1] = (prev[-1][0], prev[-1][1] + curr)
    return prev

my_list = ['a', 2, 1, 'b', 3, 'h', 50, 4, 'd', 4, 'v', 20, 7]
res = reduce(accum, my_list, [])   # [] is initializer
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('h', 54), ('d', 4), ('v', 27)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of functools. Interesting approach.